# Retrieving first non-private ip for local system in elixir

Tags: functional-programming, ip-address, elixir

I've recently started learning elixir, and the following is my attempt at fetching the local IP address of the system.

It can definitely be improved further, but as this would be my first ever project in a functional language; I'd be open to any criticisms.

```
defmodule Systemip do
  def private_ipv4() do
    {:ok, addrs} = :inet.getif()

    filtered =
      Enum.filter(
        addrs,
        fn address ->
          ip = elem(address, 0)
          is_private_ipv4(ip)
        end
      )

    elem(hd(filtered), 0)
  end

  defp is_private_ipv4(ip) do
    case ip do
      {10, _x, _y, _z} ->
        true

      {192, 168, _x, _y} ->
        true

      {172, 16, _x, _y} ->
        true

      {172, 32, _x, _y} ->
        true

      _ ->
        false
    end
  end
end
```

This would be part of a larger project, which is still under construction. The IPs are fetched using the erlang call to `:inet.getif`, the formatting was done by `mix format` command.

Comment: Very interesting code! Definitely willing to take a crack at this, which I'll do as soon as I get a chance. I deleted an earlier question that was obvious when I read your question properly :)

Answer (score 2):

There is few problems there:

1. There is no `:inet.getif/0` function listed in [`inet` module docs](https://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html), which mean that if such function exists, then it is non-public API and **should not** be called. You probably wanted to call `:inet.getifaddrs/0`.
2. `hd/1` will fail if `filtered` list is empty
3. You traverse whole list to find only first entry.
4. In Elixir, by convention, boolean returning functions, that aren't guard safe (so all user-defined boolean returning functions), should use `?` suffix instead of `is_` prefix.
5. Use pattern matching instead of `elem/2` if possible.
6. This will raise error if there will be error during fetching interfaces addresses.
7. Your IP ranges are invalid, as whole `172.16.0.0/12` is private, which is range from `172.16.0.0` to `172.31.255.255` where you were checking only for `172.16.c.d` and `172.32.c.d` where the second group is in public space.

---

To fix all the issues there you can write it as:

```
defmodule SystemIP do
  def private_ipv4() do
    with {:ok, addrs} <- :inet.getif() do
      Enum.find_value(addrs, fn {if_name, if_opts} ->
        case Keyword.fetch(if_opts, :addr) do
          {:ok, adr} -> if not public_ipv4?(addr), do: addr
          _ -> false
        end
      end)
    end
  end

  defp private_ipv4?({10, _, _, _}), do: true
  defp private_ipv4?({172, b, _, _}) when b in 16..31, do: true
  defp private_ipv4?({192, 168, _, _}), do: true
  defp private_ipv4?({_, _, _, _}), do: false
end
```